# WooCommerce.getAsync API not working return value

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic2, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to many times but not return value inside nested function. I am using WooCommerce REST API inside a ionic 2 project, This API response successfully but that response not return. Please resolve my issue. I am stuck so many time and i have not any solution. Please help me :( 
I am using this plugin [WooCommerce API - Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api)

Sorry for my English. Please try to understand. ThankYou

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

  this.woocom().then((result) => {
    console.log('result===='+result);
  });

}

woocom(){
   var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
  var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
   url: 'http://test.com',
   consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  WooCommerce.getAsync('products/categories').then((result) => {
   console.log(result.toJSON().body);

   //return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body));

  // return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
 });
   return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Why you are calling return outside the method?
. it should be inside the method

Comment: @ShakeerHussain Because inside response JSON I am not use anywhere. I tried to load json inside HTML page but do not reload data HTML page.

Comment: Are you able to see result data in console.log() ?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain Yes I able to see response in console panel

Comment: Respnse = {"product_categories":[{"id":16,"name":"category 2","slug":"category-2","parent":0,"description":"this is category 2","display":"default","image":"","count":1},{"id":15,"name":"category1","slug":"category1","parent":0,"description":"this is category 1","display":"default","image":"","count":1}]}

Comment: @ShakeerHussain I am still Waiting for your response. Please help, I am stuck many time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WooCommerceResult:any=[];

 WooCommerce.getAsync('products/categories').then((result) => {
   console.log(result.toJSON().body);
this.WooCommerceResult=result.toJSON().body;
   //return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body));

  // return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
 });
```

Bind **WooCommerceResult** using *nFor in a view

Comment: Thank You for response. I globally define WooCommerceResult:any=[]; and used in html page successfully load data inside html. Thank You